# How to convert military to standard Time in javascript using the below example?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the output to say 11pm for example, instead of 2300. I am not sure how to convert it. Everything else is working out how I want it to but I don't want the output in military time

```
 <script>

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();
    var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();
    var weekdays = [
        ["Sunday", 13.00, 1700],
        ["Monday", 9.00, 2200],
        ["Tuesday", 9.00, 2200],
        ["Wednesday", 9.00, 2200],
        ["Thursday",   9.00, 2200],
        ["Friday", 9.00, 19.00],
        ["Saturday", 9.00, 17.00]
    ];
    var day = weekdays[n];

;
    if (now > day[1] && now < day[2] || now > day[3] && now < day[4]) {
        console.log("We are open today from "+ day[1]);
         document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = "We are open today from "+day[1]+"AM"+" to "+day[2];
    }
     else {
        console.log("We are currently closed. We will open at");
        document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = "We are currently closed. We will open at"+ day[1];
    }

</script>
```

Comment: `3` and `4` are not valid indexes into an array of `length = 3`. And why do some times have decimals?

Comment: I am not sure, I used a different example to create this. Maybe I did it wrong. Can you help?

Comment: I want to do something like

var hours = ["Closed",          // Sunday
             "7 AM to 5 PM",    // Monday
             "8 AM to 5 PM",    // Tuesday
             "9 AM to 3 PM",    // Wednesday
             "11 AM to 5 PM",    // Thursday
             "9 AM to 2 PM",    // Friday
             "10 AM to 2 PM"];  // Saturday

Comment: Some time values contain dot to separate hours from minutes but some don't. Which one is it gonna be.

Comment: I dont know what you mean...this is as far as I have gotten I don't know how else to fix this or make it better

Comment: I am looking for this to be written in standard time when it outputs to HTML instead of 2300

Comment: does that make sense?

Comment: Why do you need actual times at all if you're just showing static text to your users? Keep it simpe: write your opening/closing times as strings, and then template those strings into your page. Then to _check_ whether you're open or not, you have a separate object with values that _can_ be used to compare against Date.now() - heck, merge them into a single object: `const times = { monday: { 12h: ["9am", "10pm"], 24h: ["9:00", "22:00"]}, ... };` and off you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a helper function to convert military hours to am/pm.

```js
const now = new Date();
const hoursOfOperation = [
  {open: 13, close: 17},
  {open: 9, close: 22},
  {open: 9, close: 22},
  {open: 9, close: 22},
  {open: 9, close: 22},
  {open: 9, close: 19},
  {open: 9, close: 17}
];

function hourToString(hour)
{
  if (hour === 0) return "Midnight";
  else if (hour === 12) return "Noon";
  else if (hour > 12) return `${hour-12} PM`;
  else return `${hour} AM`;
  
  // Shorter version without Midnight and Noon
  // return ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1) + (hour >= 12 ? " PM":" AM");
}

const today = hoursOfOperation[now.getDay()];
if (now.getHours() >= today.open && now.getHours() < today.close) {
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = `We are open today from ${hourToString(today.open)} to ${hourToString(today.close)}`;
}
else {
  const nextDay = hoursOfOperation[(now.getDay() + 1) % 6];
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = `We are currently closed. We will open tomorrow at ${hourToString(nextDay.open)}`;
}
```

```html
<div id='example'></div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was trying to do, THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

You might want to display opening and closing time as `Date` objects, so comparing them with current date would be easier. Also you should consider using a partial to create dates because we know that the year, month and day of the month would be constant among all schedule records. Also it's recommended to use JS provided interfaces to manipulate dates when it's possible. Here we better use `toLocaleString` to get a time format as we wish. So the below snippet of code might be useful:

```js
const currentDate = new Date();

const createShceduleDate = (hours, minutes) =>
  new Date(
    currentDate.getFullYear(),
    currentDate.getMonth(),
    currentDate.getDate(),
    hours,
    minutes
  );

const get12HourDate = (date) =>
  date.toLocaleString("en-US", { hour: "numeric", hour12: true });

const schedule = [
  ["Sunday", createShceduleDate(13, 0), createShceduleDate(17, 0)],
  ["Monday", createShceduleDate(9, 0), createShceduleDate(22, 0)],
  ["Tuesday", createShceduleDate(9, 0), createShceduleDate(22, 0)],
  ["Wednesday", createShceduleDate(9, 0), createShceduleDate(22, 0)],
  ["Thursday", createShceduleDate(9, 0), createShceduleDate(22, 0)],
  ["Friday", createShceduleDate(9, 0), createShceduleDate(22, 0)],
  ["Saturday", createShceduleDate(9, 0), createShceduleDate(22, 0)],
];

const matchingDate = schedule[currentDate.getDay()];

if (matchingDate[1] <= currentDate && matchingDate[2] >= currentDate) {
  console.log(
    `We are currently open. (${matchingDate[0]}, from ${get12HourDate(
      matchingDate[1]
    )} to ${get12HourDate(matchingDate[2])})`
  );
} else {
  document.getElementById(
    "example"
  ).innerHTML = `We are currently closed. We will open at ${get12HourDate(
    schedule[(currentDate.getDay() + 1) % 6][1]
  )}`;
}
```

```html
<p id="example"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use a function to convert the military time.

```
function convertTime24to12(militarytime) {
    let time = militarytime/100
    let hours = parseInt(time, 10)-12
    return hours
}

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();
var weekdays = [
    ["Sunday", 13.00, 1700],
    ["Monday", 9.00, 2200],
    ["Tuesday", 9.00, 2200],
    ["Wednesday", 9.00, 2200],
    ["Thursday",   9.00, 2200],
    ["Friday", 9.00, 1900],
    ["Saturday", 9.00, 1700]
];

var day = weekdays[n];

    if (now > day[1] && now < day[2] || now > day[3] && now < day[4]) {
        // console.log("We are open today from "+ day[1]);
        console.log("We are open today from "+day[1]+"AM"+" to "+convertTime24to12(day[2])+"PM");
        //  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = "We are open today from "+day[1]+"AM"+" to "+convertTime24to12(day[2])+"PM";
    }
     else {
        console.log("We are currently closed. We will open at " + day[1]);
        // document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = "We are currently closed. We will open at"+ day[1];
    }
```

Comment: Note: I made sure all the "Military Times" are not in decimals.